# Websphere application server not supporting Deutsche Telekom Root certificate

Tags: ssl, https, websphere, ssl-certificate, root-certificate

We are consuming xml from different datasources. Some are http and some are https. HTTPS with Verisign certificates are working without any issues. However, URLs with Deutsche Telekom Root certificate is not working. The web sphere application server is having the default root certificate which was generated while creating a WAS profile. Do I have to add any other special certificate to make Deutsche Telekom Root certificate work ? Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I know enough about your setup yet.  So by default WebSphere creates it's own root certificate, nothing about it would trust a Verisign certificate.  So I wonder about what you are using to make the https connection?  It could be something that manages to bypass the WebSphere socket factories and you are actually using the JRE's default,  and the cacerts file for trust.   Verisign certs are in the cacerts file there are no Deutsche Telekom as far as I can tell.

Or was a Verisign certificate added to your WebSphere truststore at some time?

Typically you have establish trust to make WebSphere trust another server.  Retrieving a certificate from a port is a good way to do that.

Alaine

Answer (score 0):

Please, post the WAS version you use.

The reason you cannot setup the connection to ssl port is that WAS doesn't trust to the ssl certificate of the remote host.

You have to add the whole certificate chain of the remote host to the WAS truststore.

You can find the example of how to add the certificate by following link https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CE0QFjAHahUKEwiRy4zsztzGAhXCfHIKHVq-BfM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webspheretools.com%2Fsites%2Fwebspheretools.nsf%2Fdocs%2FBasic%2520SSL%2520terminalogy%2520and%2520Tips%2520for%2520WebSphere%2520Application%2520Server.Default%2520passwords%2520for%2520SSL%2520keyfile%2520and%2520Truststore.&ei=DwymVdGHDcL5yQPa_JaYDw&usg=AFQjCNE42W06AILWb99iYWiUp7EcbT92iw&sig2=KKYyvAsFET1Ae0fOLSl8zA&bvm=bv.97949915,d.bGQ